# What is an application adapters for hosted application in CCA?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, crm

I am new  to Microsoft CRM CCA . Currently  i am faceing some problems .
i created an winform and hosted it in my Agent Desktop . The winform is supposed to show the contents of a notepad in  the winform's text area . How to achieve it ? I have no clue at all as there is not a much documentation  on this topic .   .....Plz help me out here .

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should show us your current progress (code) and the error you occur. You current question doesn't give enough information and sounds more like "do it for me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan to create an hosted application with an adapter then yoou have to use `AIF(application intregation frame work)` yOU CAN CHECK OUT THIS LINK [hosted control](https://github.com/TheThirdRichNiggers/CCA_HostedControl.git)

and [application adapter](https://github.com/TheThirdRichNiggers/CCA_external_adapter.git)

Answer (score 3):

here you go the complete code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Uii.Csr;

namespace Microsoft.Uii.QuickStarts
{
    public partial class QsHostedControl : HostedControl
    {
        public QsHostedControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Necessary constructor
        public QsHostedControl(Guid appID, string appName, string initString)
            : base(appID, appName, initString)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void QSHostedControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

        // This is the context change event handler.
        public override void NotifyContextChange(Context context)
        {
            // This is the context change handler.

            // Populating text fields from context information.
            txtFirstName.Text = context["CustomerFirstName"];
            txtLastName.Text = context["CustomerLastName"];
            txtAddress.Text = context["Street"];
            txtID.Text = context["CustomerID"];

            // Hands control back over to the base class to notify next app of context change.
            base.NotifyContextChange(context);
        }

        protected override void DoAction(RequestActionEventArgs args)
        {
            //Check the action name to see if it's something we know how to handle and perform appropriate work
            switch (args.Action)
            {
                case "UpdateFirstName":
                    txtFirstName.Text = args.Data;
                    break;

                case "UpdateLastName":
                    txtLastName.Text = args.Data;
                    break;                  

            }
        }

        private void updateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This is how you fire an action to other hosted applications. Your DoAction() code
            // in your other application or application adapter will get called via this.
            FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("QSExternalApplication", "UpdateFirstName", txtFirstName.Text));
            FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("QSExternalApplication", "UpdateLastName", txtLastName.Text));

            FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("QSWebApplication", "UpdateFirstName", txtFirstName.Text));
            FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("QSWebApplication", "UpdateLastName", txtLastName.Text));
            FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("QSWebApplication", "UpdateAddress", txtAddress.Text));
            FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("QSWebApplication", "UpdateID", txtID.Text));
        }

        private void btnFireContextChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the current context and create a new context object from it.
            string temp = Context.GetContext();
            Context updatedContext = new Context(temp);

            // Update the new context with the changed information.
            updatedContext["CustomerFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            updatedContext["CustomerLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;

            // Notify everyone of this new context information
            FireChangeContext(new ContextEventArgs(updatedContext));
            // Tell self about this change
            NotifyContextChange(updatedContext);

        }
    }
}
```

you can find it in sdk also